# rsync unable to connect error

Tags: github, ftp, travis-ci, rsync, cloudflare

I am trying to use rsync to upload files to my server alongside Travis and GitHub, I have this line in a deploy.sh script `rsync -avhP $f deploy@multicrew.co.uk:/var/www/test/` and whenever I try to upload the $f files I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host multicrew.co.uk port 22: Cannot assign requested address
```

Within my .travis.yml file I have this code

```
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: multicrew.co.uk

before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_8c9513462553_key -iv $encrypted_8c9513462553_iv -in deploy/deploy_rsa.enc -out /tmp/deploy_rsa -d
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - chmod 600 /tmp/deploy_rsa
  - ssh-add /tmp/deploy_rsa
  - chmod +x deploy/deploy.sh

after_success: "deploy/deploy.sh"
```

I do not know why rsync cannot assign the requested address, I have an A name record set up within CloudFlare that forwards multicrew.co.uk to my server's IP

Comment: try to ssh with to the given box with -V option. It will tell you more details why it is failing. Check https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2014/09/24/ssh-port-forwarding-bind-cannot-assign-requested-address/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting looks like it is caused by an outstanding [issue with IPv6 on Travis CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8711).

However because, at the time of writing, your multicrew.co.uk domain is proxied by Cloudflare and [Cloudflare only proxies HTTP traffic](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169406-How-do-I-SSH-), the suggested fix of disabling IPv6 will not work.

You'll need to either [create a separate non-proxied (grey cloud) hostname](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169096-How-do-I-add-A-records-) to use with SSH/RSYNC, change the rsync command to connect directly to the server IP address or disable Cloudflare proxying for the multiview.co.uk hostname.

Note that adding a non-proxied hostname in DNS will expose your server's IP address. You might want to restrict access on your server to just the [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ip-addresses/) and [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) IP ranges (e.g. with firewall rules or in the web server configuration).

Comment: How do I make a second hostname?

Comment: You can create a hostname using the Cloudflare DNS settings. See https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169096-How-do-I-add-A-records-

Comment: But I already have a host name under the name multicrew.co.uk so how could I make a second one that has restricted access to just Travis and Cloudflare?

Comment: You could add a new 'ssh.multicrew.co.uk' hostname pointing at your server's IP. This hostname would be left unproxied (grey cloud) to allow direct access to your server. The main 'multicrew.co.uk' and 'www.multicrew.co.uk' hostnames can remain proxied (orange cloud). Restricting direct access to your server's IP address would have to be done with firewall rules or web server configuration on your server.

Comment: Could I restrict access just to the ssh.multicrew.co.uk link?